# Working with very large Javascript array or objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

Currently I'm working on a script where I've got to store more than 1,250,000 objects. I'm using the `push()` function in a jQuery `each()` loop like this:

```
words.push({
  "page": pagenumber,
  "content": word,
  "hpos": $(this).attr("HPOS"),
  "vpos": $(this).attr("VPOS"),
  "width": $(this).attr("WIDTH"),
  "height": $(this).attr("HEIGHT")
});
```

In Chrome it goes quit fast, between 30 and 40 seconds, but in Internet Explorer it can take up to 360 seconds.

It's for a project where old newspapers are loaded and you can search the text from those newspapers. The newspapers are in a directory and are loaded dynamically. In this test I'm doing I'm using newspapers from october 1926, containing 308 pages and over 1.250.000 words.

Is there a better/faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give us some background as to why you're creating an array of 1.25 million objects?

Comment: You should better think about, if you really need 1m+ entries in a JavaScript object in a browser.

Comment: @zerkms: There's no concept of pre-allocating with JavaScripts untyped arrays, because [they're not really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

Comment: Can we see the *entire* code?

Comment: I can't ever think of a reason to add so many items to a client side array. I think you need to explain your rationale, and give us more insight in to the goals of your project. Its likely you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: http://jsperf.com/array-allocation - that's interesting, thanks

Comment: One way to speed it up a bit is to use a [faster loop than `$.each()`](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/31), but I doubt IE is ever going to be happy about 1.25mil objects.

Comment: Also, regarding the edit, loading and indexing the newspapers is definitely a job for the server.

Comment: @Juhana what if the server is node.js ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Well, NodeJS uses V8, which is what Chrome uses, and the OP seems reasonably happy with the 30-40 seconds Chrome takes. And of course, V8 in NodeJS is unshackled by browser-specific issues. And servers tend to be faster than desktops. And the result could be reused across requests.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Not sure what you mean, but it would still be better. At least you could do some caching and serve only what the user requests. Sounds like this is the kind of data (newspaper archives) that doesn't change over time.

Comment: @Juhana my point was the performance tuning of javascript is useful, even if doing it in the client is a bad idea.

Comment: I never said you shouldn't do performance tuning, but if this is moved to the server you probably wouldn't work directly with the DOM (even with node.js) so the code snippet shown here would be completely re-written anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `on myth of javascript array` is that the reason why `typeof([])` returns `"object"`?

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound: Maybe. Primarily that's just the way `typeof` is defined in the spec. `typeof` is really only for testing primitives from references types. If you want to get into more detail, you use `Object.prototype.toString`. More on my blog: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a better/faster way to achieve this?

Yes: Do it on a server, not in the browser. This also has the advantage that you can do it once and reuse the information.

But assuming for some reason that's not possible:

The first thing you can do is stop making several million unnecessary function calls by only doing `$(this)` **once** per loop:

```
.....each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    words.push({
        "page": pagenumber,
        "content": word,
        "hpos": $this.attr("HPOS"),
        "vpos": $this.attr("VPOS"),
        "width": $this.attr("WIDTH"),
        "height": $this.attr("HEIGHT")
    });
});
```

Normally repeatedly doing that isn't a big deal (though I'd avoid it anyway), but if you're doing this one and a quarter million times...

And if all of those attributes really are attributes, you can avoid the call entirely by cutting jQuery out of the middle:

```
.....each(function () {
    words.push({
        "page": pagenumber,
        "content": word,
        "hpos": this.getAttribute("HPOS"),
        "vpos": this.getAttribute("VPOS"),
        "width": this.getAttribute("WIDTH"),
        "height": this.getAttribute("HEIGHT")
    });
});
```

jQuery's `attr` function is great and smooths over all sorts of cross-browser hassles with certain attributes, but I don't think any of those four needs special handling, not even on IE, so you can just use DOM's `getAttribute` directly.

The next thing is that some JavaScript engines execute `push` more slowly than assigning to the end of the array. These two statements do the same thing:

```
myarray.push(entry);
// and
myarray[myarray.length] = entry;
```

But other engines process `push` as fast or faster than the assignment (it is, after all, a ripe target for optimization). So you might look at whether IE does `push` more slowly and, if so, switch to using assignment instead.

Comment: Thanks, it has speeded thing up a little, but I think I'll going to give node.js a try. Trying to let the server do all the hard work and not the browser.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Doesn't `myarray[myarray.length] = entry;` create a sparse array? Might not be a problem in this case, but it can change the behavior of the array for certain applications.

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux: No, it doesn't. It just adds an entry to the end of the array, like `push` does. Assigning a value to `length` to make it larger (`var a = []; a.length = 10;`) creates a sparse array, but adding to the end of an array doesn't.